# Possible censored data and Tobit regression

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, tobit-regression

I want to study the impact of highways on deforestation. I am using annual data on forest cover. I define my deforestation/forest loss variable as a change in forest cover and if the change is zero or positive my deforestation/forest loss variable is zero. Does this imply truncated or censored data and thus requiring the use of a Tobit regression? I am hesitant to use Tobit because of the problems of including fixed effects.

Comment: The fixed-effects model involves subtracting the forest-mean from each forest-year to isolate within-forest change. Your forest-mean is not an intuitively meaningful value after adding all the zeros, in my opinion. My intuition is that you'll want to choose a different strategy. I might have an idea depending on the following: How is the highway variable coded in the data? Is it continuous (i.e. miles of highway) or dichotomous (zero until a highway arrives, then 1)? What's the logic in only including forest-years with losses?

Comment: Thank you for this reply, sorry for the late reply. Highway is coded as a dummy variable.

Comment: I still don't understand censoring the positive years. It sounds like the data you are describing above is "first-differenced" already.  If you are working with differenced data, you should not need forest fixed-effects on top of that. Do you start with a value that is like "forest mass" that stays positive but fluctuates? If you are starting with a "forest mass" type value, I have a specific suggestion: use the "forest mass" value and perform a [Difference-in-Differences with variation in treatment timing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/did/vignettes/did-basics.html).